# Executing two statements alternatively,inside a loop

Tags: c, loops

I have two statements inside a loop that iterate a large number of times.

I need to alternate the execution of the two statements, with every iteration.

What is the most efficient way of achieving it?
Can I do it without using an additional variable?

I'm coding in C by the way...

PS: I thought of using bitwise operators on an 8bit int value(int8_t) , to extract the LSB. Then I increment the inteager by 1,in every iteration,so that the LSB holds an alternating 1and 0.
Can I do better?

Comment: Why not just loop half as many times and have the loop body execute both statements

Comment: share your code that would help us to know.

Comment: Are you really tight on RAM in some embedded device?  Why not use a simple 'doXnotYthisTime' boolean and move on the next problem?

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought...But I was wondering if there was a better way...

Answer (score 4):

Just use the mod `%` with value `2` on your counter. Odd numbers give one, even numbers give zero. Alternatively, you could also use the bitwise operator & and compare to 1, to get the same results. The first option is more general and can be extended to multiple options, whereas the second option is faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    if (i % 2)
    // if (i & 1)
      printf("%d, Option a\n", i);
    else
      printf("%d, Option b\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: a number modulus 2 gives either 1 or 0

Comment: "The first option is more general, whereas the second is faster.". The second option will only work for powers of two. Besides, if your compiler doesn't know that `% 2` can be turned into `& 1` in machine code, please change it.

Comment: @pmg You could use a modulus `3` and then check for `0`, `1` and `2`. That is what I mean with more general.

Comment: "Odd numbers give one, even numbers give **zero**."

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar. I find it a good philosophy to not count too much on such things and deliver the simplest code possible. Nonetheless, you are probably right, my compiler knowledge is too limited.